# Would Keychain be safer than Firefox Password Manager?

Tags: mac, firefox, passwords, keychain

Theoretically speaking would Keychain be safer to use in Firefox than Firefox's own password manager? The reason I ask is because Chrome is using Keychain.

Comment: see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/20168/how-safe-is-firefox-password-manager) SU question

Comment: Thanks Raystafarian. One person in the comments mentioned Keychain would be more integrated than FF password manager. I'm guessing there are advantages or disadvantages to this approach.

Comment: A centralized password manager has many usability advantages though — you only need to enter the master password once, it's easier to migrate and sync passwords, and you can browse all passwords in a single interface like Keychain Access. I don't really see why people keep using Firefox over a browser with better platform integration like Safari.

Comment: Thanks LRI. I've been reading up on this. What do you think of Mozilla Sync?

Comment: Firefox has keychain integration services for mac users

Comment: @mossy Do you mean the [Keychain Services Integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keychain-services-integration/) extension?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts, I didn't get a notification of the comment — apparently the capitalization of the username has to match... I guess Firefox Sync would make sense if have to use other platforms than OS X and iOS (and don't use something like 1Password).

Comment: @Lri - It looks like they added an auto-complete since I last visited to help people with this. I do have to use other platforms.

Answer (score 5):

Keychain is encrypted by default whereas Firefox password manager is not encrypted by default. You can use a master password with Firefox password manager at `tools - options - security tab - use master password` but ultimately FF password manager is nearly 100% unsafe without a master password

Comment: Note to self: Apply master password

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use a master password with Firefox, anyone with access to your computer can currently install an extension like [Password Exporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/) and export all saved passwords in clear text.

Comment: yikes! got it. note to self: apply master password